# Should my session class be static?

Tags: php, session

I've always been told be be very careful when creating static classes as they have a tendency to be overused by less skilled programmers.

I'm currently writing a session class in PHP to keep track of a user on the site.

A session seems like it would make sense being in a static class because there is only ever going to be one of them right?

I used to work in a CMS that had a factory which created a session object but then stored the instance and when ever a new session was requested ( MyFactory::getSession() ) it would return the previously initialised one. Is there any advantage to this?

Thanks!

Comment: No, `MyFactory::getSession()` doesn't make much sense, and yes, using a static class would be fine.

Comment: I think you can juggle multiple sessions if you were so inclined.

Comment: Why would you want multiple sessions?

Comment: @Undefined , you might want a different session wrapper which implements same interface. If your code is tied to the name of the class ( which is the case with static classes ) then you cannot replace the session instances *"on fly"*. This is what people mean when they talk about *close coupled code*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, classes should **never** be static, if you are doing object oriented programming. That applies to factories too. The Static factory method pattern ( which you showed in the example ) is considered a bad practices, because it violates [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

The static variables are just globals by different name and static methods are namespaced function, where the namespace just happens to look like class.

If you need multiple object to use same session instance, then you should provide them all with it. Either directly or by using a factory.

```
class ObjectFactory
{

    protected $session;

    public function __construct( $session )
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public function create( $name ) 
    {
        return new $name( $this->session );
    }

}
```

You pass instance of this factory to any object, which would need create structures, that use session. You just create the objects with this factory and they all will be initialize with same session instance.

In more simplified example you can just pass the session to each object manually:

```
$session = new Session;

$user = new User( $session );
$article = new Document( $session );
```

Both `$user` and `$article` instances now will share the same session instance.

For more information, watch the following presentations:

- [Global State and Singletons](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FRm3VPhseI)
- [Don't Look For Things!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0)